# My app crashes in other languages. Xibs seem to not be loaded. Why?

Tags: ios

I have an app that is localized for two languages: English and Danish. If I set the device to any other language (say, French) the app crashes. It seems as if it's not really loading the XIB files, or getting a generic version of them that is not properly initialized.

I guess that I naively assumed that the app would load the English version if it was set for a language other than English or Danish.

What do I do? Is there a way to ensure that behavior?

Comment: Hmm. Could it be because for those particular XIB's they only exist in the en.lproj and da.lproj directories, and not in - say - the project root? If so, what's the proper way to fix it?

Comment: Another odd thing: The project has somehow ended up having several .lproj folders. It has: /English.lproj /da.lproj /Classes/en.lproj and /Classes/da.lproj. Thus: Two folders for English, wih different names, and in different locations. I have no idea how XCode did this to me, and I don't care, but is that the root cause of the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause:
Somehow XCode had created two sets of en.lproj and da.lproj directories. One set was in the project root (oh, an en.lproj was here called English.lproj) and the other was in Classes. The "missing" XIB files were in the directory in Classes.

Solution:
Copy XIB files to the proper folders in the root. Remove original ones from project (go ahead and say move to thrash, you just copied them...). Add copies in proper location to project - all in one drag operation - and do not copy to project (they are already in the proper location).

Answer (score 0):

The app should load the english version if you set the device language to, for example, french.

You should give some details how you are loading the XIB. 
It's rather impossible to give an answer to this question without knowledge about your specific implementation.

Comment: One of the view controllers is loaded via another XIB. The other one is loaded explicitly via     self.embeddedPredictionsViewController = [[EmbeddedPredictions alloc] initWithNibName:@"EmbeddedPredictions" bundle:Nil];
For the latter I get this error message: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/andersprivat/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/AB90AB30-8FF5-4768-899F-E564DA2EB981/TypOHD.app> (loaded)' with name 'EmbeddedPredictions''"