# Project has both English.lproj and en.lproj. How to fix it?

Tags: ios

It seems that my project has somehow acquired two folders for English resources: /English.lproj and /Classes/en.lproj. Obviously this seems wrong, and although it works when devise is set to English, I suspect that it causes a crashing issue when the device is set for non.English language (app can't find the default resources - [My app crashes in other languages. Xibs seem to not be loaded. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177541/my-app-crashes-in-other-languages-xibs-seem-to-not-be-loaded-why))

So how does one go about fixing this? Apparently I can't just move the files. XCode misses the old ones, and can't find the new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Basically copy the files, remove references, make new references, delete old files.

Detailed description here:
[My app crashes in other languages. Xibs seem to not be loaded. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177541/my-app-crashes-in-other-languages-xibs-seem-to-not-be-loaded-why/10194824#10194824)